# How to make or load chat application UI using single js?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, web-applications, chat

I am working on popup chat app. Back-end app is ready. 
App contain one html file and other one for js and css.

I want to make a single js file to combine above app. Whenever in feature i load this new js file automatic this pop-up chat must work.

So please suggest me, how to achive it?

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Chat</button>
    <div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
    <h1>Chat</h1>

    <label for="msg"><b>Message</b></label>
    <textarea placeholder="Type message.." name="msg" required></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

js code:

```
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
```

Ultimately, I want to load this "Popup Chat Window - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup_chat.asp" using single js file. So, I can use it for production.

Comment: @mindmaster Correct you saying. if you want to have combine data source (JS part) and UI Part(HTML) in single file, using ReactJS(https://reactjs.org) library. JSX concepts using in ReactJS.

Comment: I'll leave your explanation! It's way better than mine, that's exacly what i meant @KumarRamalingam thanks!

Comment: ok. I know basics about react. but still, Is there any other way to do it ? @KumarRamalingam